# Using "compileOnly" scope dependencies in IntelliJ Run Configuration delegated to gradle

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I am using install4j to bundle my Java application. Since install4j brings its own api, I added it as a 'compileOnly' dependency to the build.gradle

```
compileOnly(files("${project.projectDir}/lib/i4jruntime.jar"))
```

When I run the gradle task `run` the application starts as expected. So I assume the `run` task includes the compileOnly dependencies in classpath.

However when I use an IntelliJ Run Configuration for running my Main class it fails with a ClassNotFoundException:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.install4j.api.launcher.SplashScreen$ConnectionException
```

It seemed obvious to me that I had to check the 'Include dependencies with "Provided" scope' in the Run Configuration, however execution still fails.

Surprinsingly the Run Configuration only fails when I am delegating the build and run tasks to Gradle.
If I choose 'IntelliJ IDEA' in the settings for 'Build and Run using' the Run Configuration works as expected.

A sample project can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/afousk/runconfigsample). I am running `IntelliJ 2019.3.4` on Windows and with `OpenJDK 11.0.1`

Is this a bug in the IDE or am I missing something?

---

I found the small little lines in my *build.gradle* that make the `run` task work, which now makes sense to me:

```
tasks.run {
  classpath = configurations.compileClasspath + sourceSets.main.output
}
```

However I still think that checking *Include dependencies with 'Provided' scope* should make the IntelliJ run configuration work. At leas that is my expectation as a user.

Comment: What are the exact versions of IDE and JDK that you are using?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Could you provide a sample project? I can not reproduce this. When I launch Gradle `run` task it also fails for me.

Comment: I found some lines in the build file which make the ```run``` task work. Must have forgotten that I added them some day... Updated the question accordingly and added a link to a sample project

Comment: That will also properly fix running from IntelliJ with Gradle delegation.
That the option you mentioned does not have any effect may be an IntelliJ bug that you might consider reporting, but actually it would be better you fix your dependency declaration.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that compileOnly should NOT be included on the runtime classpath. That is literally what "compile only" means.

Using 'compileOnly' typically implies that some other dependency will bring along that necessary dependency when running, that is, on the runtime classpath. E.g. you need the Servlet API while coding (i.e. compiling), but in runtime, Jetty will provide the Servlet API (since Jetty depends on it, and you thus get it transitively).

Gradle does it correctly, while IntelliJ is wrong.

Here's an IntelliJ issue detailing this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247645

(Edit 2024-01-03: One wonders who is giving -1 votes to this piece of factual info..)